# $\mathbb{C}$-point of a variety and automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$.

A closed point is the topologically closed point. A $\mathbb C$-rational point is given by $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)\to X$ a **morphism of scheme over** $\mathbb{C}$.

Now, let's just take $X=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ as well for simplicity. It seems that there will be more than one rational points because we have a lot of automorphisms $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$.

I also see this (cf. Algebraic and Analytic Geometry by Amnon Neeman)[image]
I think it is wrong because of the automorphisms on $\mathbb C$. The closed point in this case corresponds to the maximal ideal of $R$. The correspondence given by taking $\ker\varphi$ to obtain the maximal ideal. But when we concatenate an automorphism $\psi$ of $\mathbb C$ or embed $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$ (there are some subfield of $\mathbb C$ isomorphic to $\mathbb C$). Say the structure homomorphism $j:\mathbb C\to R$. Then we still get a $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism $\psi\varphi:R\to\mathbb C$ by setting the structure homomorphism on the second $\mathbb C$ to be $\psi\varphi j:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$. And the kernel of $\psi\varphi$ is just the maximal ideal so we get more homomophisms than closed points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not allow all morphisms $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)\to X$, only the morphisms over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$.

Let me clarify: to say that $X$ is a scheme over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ means there is a structural morphism $X\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$. Then for any commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $A$, an $A$-point of $X$ should be a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to X$ which gives a commutative triangle with the structural morphisms $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ and $X\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$.

In particular, when $A=\mathbb C$, a $\mathbb C$-point is a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)\to X$ such that the composition $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)\to X\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ is the identity morphism of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$.

If you take that definition, $X=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ has only one $\mathbb C$-point *over $\mathbb C$*.

---

To answer your edit, you *cannot* compose with automorphisms of $\mathbb C$, because then you don't have $\mathbb C$-algebra automorphisms anymore. The only $R$-algebra automorphism of a ring $R$ is the identity. All the other automorphisms are only ring automorphisms, not $R$-algebra automorphisms.

Comment: So a $\mathbb C$-point is a $\mathbb C$-morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)\to X$ but this $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ has the structure morphism from $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ to $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ **defined** to be identity? If we allow other morphisms between them then there are again more. But why a lot of learning materials just say it is $\mathbb C$-morphism.

Comment: Maybe some notes don't insist enough on what a $\mathbb{C}$-morphism is, but by definition it is a morphism that preserves the structure over $\mathbb{C}$. For instance, the complex conjugation is *not* a $\mathbb{C}$-morphism, but only an $\mathbb{R}$-morphism.

Comment: Thank you: what does it mean exactly "Preserve the structure over $\mathbb C$"?

Comment: In the case of scheme morphisms, it is exactly what I wrote in my answer: there should be a commutative triangle with the structural morphisms. In particular, when the schemes are affine, it means that the corresponding ring morphism is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra morphism. The expression "$\mathbb{C}$-morphism" is purposely vague, to fit in a lot of contexts. Depending on the context, it should be clear what is the "structure over $\mathbb{C}$" and what is means to "perserve" it.

Comment: Now I am even not sure about $\mathbb C$-algebra morphism. Say $R$ is a commutative algebra. This is what I learnt: an $R$-algebra $A$ is a commutative ring $A$ together with a homomorphism $j:R\to A$ and an $R$-algebra homomorphism is a homomorphism $u:A\to B$ so that we have the commutative triangle. That's all, right? Now, we have two $\mathbb C$-algebras $A=B=\mathbb C$ and $i:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C=A$ the identity and $c: \mathbb C\to \mathbb C=B$ the conjugate. These two give two $\mathbb C$-algebras. Then $c:A\to B$ is an $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism.

Comment: This is perfectly right. When we say that a commutative ring $R$ is an $R$-algebra, we almost always implicitly talk about the $R$-algebra structure given by $id: R\to R$. But $R$ has as many $R$-algebra structures as there are ring endomorphisms $R\to R$ (potentially: a lot). If $f: R\to R$ is a ring endomorphism, let us write $R^f$ for the corresponding $R$-algebra (with underlying ring $R$). Then the identity function of $R$ is a ring morphism $R\to R^f$ which is not an algebra morphism, while $f:R\to R^f$ *is* an algebra morphism.

Comment: Ahh. I see. So it should be more clearly written like $\mathbb{C}^{c}$ if we really want that $\mathbb C$-algebra. It is more like a “de facto standard" in math? Now it is clear. Thank you.